# How to the detect when a combination of keys is no longer pressed?

Tags: jquery, keyboard-events, key-bindings

This is what I want to achieve (I've simplified the scenario):

1. User presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, so a hidden `div#my_div` appears
2. User releases <kbd>Tab</kbd> while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, so `div#my_div` remains visible
3. User presses <kbd>Tab</kbd> while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, so `div#my_div` changes to a random color
4. User releases <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, so `div#my_div` is hidden

It's something similar to the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> keyboard event on Windows, where the combination of those keys fires a shortcut for switching windows. And that shortcut remains visible while <kbd>Alt</kbd> is being pressed and disappears the moment <kbd>Alt</kbd> is released, and in between <kbd>Tab</kbd> can be pressed several times.

I can detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but as soon I release <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keyup event fires, even if it's being pressed:

```
$(window).keydown(function(e)
{
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.which === 9)
    {
        console.log("ctrl+tab");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$(window).keyup(function(e)
{
    if(e.which === 9)
    {
        console.log("tab");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$(window).keyup(function(e)
{
    if(e.ctrlKey)
    {
        console.log("end of feature");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

How can I achieve this task?

Comment: Note that `Ctrl+Tab` on most browsers is how you move between browser tabs... Could be a bit of an issue, users don't like their navigation habits being interfered with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing the `!` in your `keyup` handler: You want to be done when they *release* the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, right? So `!e.ctrlKey`:

```
$(window).keyup(function(e)
                {
  if(!e.ctrlKey)
  {
    console.log("end of feature");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: WOW, that worked! But why? hehe I mean, wasn't I supposed to actually detect the ctrlKey? The `!` is confusing me

Comment: @Matías: `ctrlKey` is a flag (true/false) for whether the `Ctrl` key is currently down. So if we see a `keyup` and the `Ctrl` key isn't down (the `!` is boolean "not"), we're done.

Comment: Hey TJ, what's happening is that the keyup event is firing even when I type in a textbox. And I don't want that to happen. Any ideas?

Comment: @Matías: Events "bubble" (propagate) from the element in which they originated to its parent, then *its* parent, etc. The event object has a `target` property that tells you what element the event originated in. So you could do something like this in your handler: `if ($(e.target).closest("input, textarea, select")[0]) { /* Event came from a form field */ } else { /* It didn't */ }`